# Обработка нажатия в модальном окне

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем доброго дня. Возникла проблема. 
Есть модальное окно, с 1 одной кнопкой "Да" и ссылкой "Нет". 
Данное окно появляется только при условии если форма была некорректно заполнена, вызвана и не заполнена, был сбой во время заполнения формы. В остальных случаях данное окно не появляется. Не могу написать метод который перехватывает данное модальное окно. У меня тест, который работает с формой, перед заполнением формы необходимо проверять появляется данное модельное окно или нет, если не появилось приступаем к заполнению формы, если появилось нажимаем на ссылку Нет (это приведет к закрытию формы) и приступаем к заполнению формы. Я использую Selenide. Если я использую первый вариант кода, всегда идет проверка в последнем блоке else

```
private boolean isElementDisplay(SelenideElement element) {
            try {
                return element.isEnabled();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void draftForm() {
            if ($("локатор_ссылки").is(Condition.enabled)) {
                if (isElementDisplay($("локатор_ссылки"))) {
                    if (($("локатор_ссылки").isEnabled())) {
                        $("локатор_ссылки").click();
                    }
                }

            } else {


Продолжаем заполнять форму

        }
```

Однако если я использую данный вариант кода

```
private boolean isElementDisplay(SelenideElement element) {
        try {
            return element.isEnabled();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void draftForm() {

        if (isElementDisplay($x("локатор_ссылки"))) {
            if (($("локатор_ссылки").isEnabled())) {
                $x(("локатор_ссылки")).click();
         Заполняем форму
            } else {
        Заполняем форму
            }
        }

    }
```

Ссылка на модальном окне всегда нажимается, т.е модальное окно обрабатывается, но если модальное окно не появляется, тест падает с ошибкой не найденного локатора модального окна. 
Заранее благодарен за подсказки.

Comment: а зачем вы 2 раза проеряете isEnabled?

Comment: вам нужно проверять на 2 условия сразу. `return element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed()`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно проверять сразу 2 состояния элемента перед работой с ним.

```
private boolean isElementReady(SelenideElement element) {
    try {
        return element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public void draftForm() {
    if (isElementReady($x("локатор_ссылки"))) {
        $x(("локатор_ссылки")).click();
     // Заполняем форму
    } else {
    // не заполняемформу
      }
    }
}
```